# JavaScript - Issue with object creation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I have this loop that results in an object as shown below:

```
console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]))

function solution(inputArray) {
  let arrMap = [] 

  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) { 
      arrMap.push({
        'element': inputArray[i],
        'position': i,
        'repeated': false
      })
    } 

  return arrMap
}
```

Here we have the result object.

```
[
  { element: 2, position: 0, repeated: false },
  { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 2, repeated: false },
  { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: false },
  { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: false }
]
```

I would like to make an if-statement, if the element is repeated, put the `true` key in it as shown below. This must be done while the object is being built dynamically.

```
[
  { element: 2, position: 0, repeated: true }, //<-- change for 'true'
  { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 2, repeated: true }, //<-- change for 'true'
  { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: true }, //<-- change for 'true'
  { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: true } //<-- change for 'true'
]
```

Comment: Why don’t you do it over the array, before creating the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looking for repeats as the array is being created:**

```
console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]))

function solution(inputArray) {
  let arrMap = [] 

  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) { 
        var repeated = false;
      var e = arrMap.find(s => s.element == inputArray[i])
      if(e){
        repeated = true;
        e.repeated = true;
      }
      arrMap.push({
        'element': inputArray[i],
        'position': i,
        'repeated': repeated
      })
    } 

  return arrMap
}
/*
[{
  element: 2,
  position: 0,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 1,
  position: 1,
  repeated: false
}, {
  element: 3,
  position: 2,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 5,
  position: 3,
  repeated: false
}, {
  element: 3,
  position: 4,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 2,
  position: 5,
  repeated: true
}]
*/
```

---

**Looking for repeats in the resulting object** (not very efficient)**:**

```
var arr = [
  { element: 2, position: 0, repeated: false },
  { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 2, repeated: false },
  { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: false },
  { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: false }
];

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (arr[j].element == arr[i].element) {
        arr[i].repeated = true;
      arr[j].repeated = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
/*
[{
  element: 2,
  position: 0,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 1,
  position: 1,
  repeated: false
}, {
  element: 3,
  position: 2,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 5,
  position: 3,
  repeated: false
}, {
  element: 3,
  position: 4,
  repeated: true
}, {
  element: 2,
  position: 5,
  repeated: true
}]
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first loop over the array once and fill an object representing the frequency of each element. An element is repeated if its frequency is greater than one. This method runs in `O(n)` time, as it does not require a loop within a loop.

```
const freq = inputArray.reduce((obj,cur)=>(obj[cur]=(obj[cur]||0)+1,obj), {});
for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) { 
      arrMap.push({
        'element': inputArray[i],
        'position': i,
        'repeated': freq[inputArray[i]] > 1
      })
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use an Object instead. Sets and Maps are for cases when your key is on non-string type. Like an oject.

Answer (score 2):

For sake of simplicity you should set the flags as you are creating your object.

From your example output, since we need to mark both (or more) instances of a number as repeated, we need to go through the entire array first.

Here's code that does what you want with comments below:

```
/// This function will return an Array with the duplicates in your input array.

const findDuplicates = (arr) => {
  let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort();

  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}


function solution(inputArray) {
  let arrMap = [] 
  
  /// Call findDuplicates function on input array.

  let duplicatesArray = findDuplicates(inputArray);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    let repeatedBoolean = false;

    /// We check if the number whose entry we are about to insert is a duplicate 
    /// number, by checking if it is in the duplicatesArray we produced by the 
    /// function findDuplicates function call.

    if (duplicatesArray.includes(inputArray[i])) {
      repeatedBoolean = true;
    }
      arrMap.push({
        'element': inputArray[i],
        'position': i,
        'repeated': repeatedBoolean
      })
    } 

  return arrMap
}

console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]));
```

The output:

```
[
  { element: 2, position: 0, repeated: true },
  { element: 1, position: 1, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 2, repeated: true },
  { element: 5, position: 3, repeated: false },
  { element: 3, position: 4, repeated: true },
  { element: 2, position: 5, repeated: true }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function solution(array) {
  return array.map((element, position, originalArray) => {
    const copyArray = [...originalArray];
    copyArray.splice(position, 1);

    return {
      element,
      position,
      repeated: copyArray.includes(element),
      // or
      //repeated: originalArray.filter(el => el === element).length > 1
    };
  });
}


console.log(solution([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]))
```